# The code in the @Bean marked function in Spring Boot is not executed

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Component("example")
public class Example {

    private Consumer<String> exampleHandler = new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    };

    @Bean
    public WorkClass workClass(Example example){
        // The code inside this is not executed
        example.exampleHandler.accept("Hello");
        return new WorkClass();
    }
}
```

I don't have any ideas to solve this problem.

As expected, an instance of Example should be created first, and then the workClass function should be executed

----------------update---------------------------------

The specific code in the workClass function is as follows, which is the code in my real project.

```
   @Bean
    public DefaultMQPushConsumer canalSyncConsumer(CanalSyncConsumerConfig canalSyncConsumerConfig) throws MQClientException {
        RPCHook rpcHook = new AclClientRPCHook(new SessionCredentials(mqProperties.getAccessKey(), mqProperties.getSecretKey()));
        DefaultMQPushConsumer consumer = new DefaultMQPushConsumer(null, "GID_MEMBER_CENTER_CANAL_SYNC_GROUP", rpcHook);
        consumer.setNamesrvAddr(mqProperties.getNamesAddr());
        final String subE = StringUtils.join(MONITOR_TABLE_NAMES, "||");
        consumer.subscribe("mq_data_mid_platform_sync", subE);
        consumer.registerMessageListener(canalSyncConsumerConfig.consumerHandler);
        consumer.start();
        return consumer;
    }
```

Comment: Show the part of your code that you expect to have a `WorkClass` instance injected.

Comment: @tgdavies WorkClass is empty

Comment: I updated the problem description, please check it out.

Comment: @Bean function cannot be intercepted in DEBUG mode

Comment: Spring should definitely create WorkClass eagerly. Is Example created?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my problem is because the same type of Bean is defined elsewhere, and the name is also called "workClass", which leads to overwriting. i'm so stupid

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Configuration
    @Component("example")
    public class Example {
    
        private Consumer<String> exampleHandler = new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String s) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        };
    
        @Bean
        public WorkClass workClass(Example example){
            // The code inside this is not executed
            example.exampleHandler.accept("Hello");
            return new WorkClass();
        }
    }
```

adding the **@Configuration** should do the trick if your project is setup properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my problem is because the same type of Bean is defined elsewhere, and the name is also called "workClass", which leads to overwriting. i'm so stupid